# Suggestions for an Oracle data modeler that can reverse engineer and handle very large databases

Tags: oracle, data-modeling, toad

By very large, I mean on the realm of thousands of tables.  I've been able to use Toad Data Modeler to do the reverse engineering, but once it loads up the txp file it creates, it just croaks.  Even attempting to split up the model isn't possible as TDM just sits, frozen.

So, I was wondering what other options are out there, and perhaps if there are any 32 bit applications that can handle such a database model (considering the memory used by this is ~750MB, I would think it not too large for a 32 bit computer with max RAM).

Also to note, I am not trying to create a diagram with this (such a huge diagram would be effectively useless unless you already knew the system), but am instead needing to export the design of the database.  So the data model tool doesn't need to support any sort of fanciful graphics, which may not be possible with the given size anyways.

Edit:
I've found a potential solution which leads to TDM working.  You have to close the project, close TDM, open TDM, and then open the project.  If you just kill the process while it is frozen, this will not work.  What this does is zoom the screen showing the graphical representation to the normal view level, while normally after reverse engineering, the entire database is put into the view (if you just kill the process, when you open up the file again, you will see the entire database).  While I am not certain the details, it appears being zoomed it makes it so that TDM runs much smoother and does not freeze or crash, and as such I am able to keep working in it to do what I need.

Comment: When you say Toad croaks, do you mean literally?  I think there's an option to disable that.  :)

Comment: Exactly what kind of data are you looking for?  If you just want the table DDL, you can try DBMS_METADATA.GET_DDL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about Oracle's own [SQL Developer Data Modeler](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/datamodeler/overview/index.html)?

Comment: I already had it downloaded before I figured a way to get TDM to work.  I'll keep it around as backup in case I hit a more difficult problem with TDM.  Thanks.  That being said, I'm not sure if this will be able to handle such large databases... I'll test it out and get back to you.